# Is [7]сirculene aromatic or anti-aromatic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromaticity

This compound is called [7]circulene and is one of the examples of non-planar aromatic systems (1). From the first overview of this compound, it is observed that there are 7 benzene rings so one would conclude that it is an aromatic compound:

[image: 7 circulene]

There are $7 \times 4 = 28$ $\pi$-electrons, so this compound satisfies the criteria of anti-aromacity. Then how come this compound is aromatic?

(1) Smith, M. March’s advanced organic chemistry: reactions, mechanisms, and structure, 7th ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, New Jersey, **2013**, p. 48, compound 40.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**TL;DR:** We don't count π *electrons* here, rather the π *conjugated circuits* [[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-1280(89)85141-3)]. [7]-сirculene has all conjugated circles of size $4n + 2,$ and none of $2n,$ what makes it an aromatic compound.

Strictly speaking, the aromaticity $4n + 2$ and antiaromaticity $4n$ rules in their original interpretation are very limited and cannot be universally applied.
According to the *original* Hückel $4n + 2$ rule, if a *monocyclic*, *planar* molecule has $4n + 2$ π *electrons*, it is considered aromatic.

But the count of π electrons is not what matters for *polycyclic* compounds, therefore a generalized $4n + 2$ rule exists: if a conjugated molecule has only $4n + 2$ π *conjugated circuits*, it is considered aromatic.

Non-benzenoid compounds can have both $4n + 2$ as well as $4n$ number of conjugated circuits counted by taking into account all Kekule structures. Among non-benzenoid non-alternant polycyclic hydrocarbons [5]-сirculene and [7]-сirculene both have only $4n + 2$ $(6, 10, 14, \dots)$ numbers of circuits.

Further reading: [Is there any special rules for checking the aromaticity of polycyclic compounds?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6109)

#### Reference

1. Gutman, I.; Cyvin, S. J. Conjugated Circuits in Benzenoid Hydrocarbons. *J. Mol. Struct. THEOCHEM* 1**989**, 184 (1), 159–163. DOI: [10.1016/0166-1280(89)85141-3](https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-1280(89)85141-3).